# How to disable all notification sounds in Android 6?

Tags: audio

I want the simplest way to say that I should never hear audible notifications from apps.

I don't want to have to configure apps individually, and once I set all app notifications to mute, newly added apps should still be mute.

I am happy to install a new app to do this, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings>Sound & Notification>Volumes and tap on 'Notification sound' icon to mute it or drag handle to the left.
Or press Volume + or - than expand volume panel and drag handle to the left or tap icon (for notification sound)

Comment: I do not have a "notification sound" option /icon. I have "when device is locked", "App notifcations", and "notification access". I had expected it ot be in "App notifcations", but that doesn't help :-(

Comment: Press volume - button on your phone you should get slider for ringtone, and expand button, what do you get when press expand button? What phone do you own?